# Dos batch - basic if/else not working

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have:

```
@echo off
echo before
IF 1 == 1 (
    echo got it
) ELSE (
    echo missed
}
echo done
```

This code just prints "before" and nothing else. I have no idea what I'm missing...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've got the wrong kind of bracket at the end of your ELSE - you've got `}` instead of `)`. Changing it to:

```
@echo off
echo before
IF 1 == 1 (
    echo got it
) ELSE (
    echo missed
)
echo done
```

the output is:

```
before
got it
done
```

Comment: Wow! Talk about dumb!! In 11 minutes Jon I'll be able to accept your answer.

Comment: @Step This is your 11 minute reminder to accept his answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

this works just like if else in nested style

```
IF %CHUSEL%==0 (
  SET IP=10.148.24.1
) ELSE (
  IF %CHUSEL%==1 (
      SET IP=10.148.24.2
  ) ELSE (
      IF %CHUSEL%==2 (
          SET IP=10.148.24.3
      ) ELSE (
          IF %CHUSEL%==3 (
             SET IP=10.148.24.4
          )
      )
   )
)
```